# Disable RSS Feed

Tags: rss

I want to disable rss feed,my wordpress version is **5.2.4**.

see my code below to disable rss feed.

```
 function itsme_disable_feed() {
 wp_die( __( 'No feed available' ) );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
```

By the book,the feed page will show wp_die page.But it didn`t show it Expectantly.

It shows this,see the screenshot,and I don`t know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Have you flushed rewrite rules and cleared any layers of caching?

Comment: yeah,I have flushed the permalink and cleared the browser cach

Comment: @Cindy Lu Hope this referrence helpful for you https://wpcaptain.com/blog/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-completely-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the HTTP Response code in `wp_die` function.

```php
wp_die( __('No feed available'), '', 404 );
```

Also set custom header to get HTML page instead of xml page. So the code should be like below.

```php
function itsme_disable_feed() {
 global $wp_query;
 $wp_query->is_feed = false;
 $wp_query->set_404();
 status_header( 404 );
 nocache_headers();
 wp_die( __('No feed available'), '', 404 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using remove_action?

Example:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_feeds_in_head', 1);

function remove_feeds_in_head() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
}
```

EDIT: So disabling them doesn't remove them, to completely get rid of them, them you need to use remove_action aswell. Assuming this is what you want to do.

```
add_action('do_feed', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
// Add whatever other things you want to remove
```

Comment: yeah,but your function just remove the feed link from source code.

Comment: @CindyLu I just updated my answer to give a little more clarity.